# How to use cloud storage from android app?

Tags: android

In my app i thought to save some text contents in cloud and retrieve it when it require. So, how can i do this in android? Can anyone show some samples that using cloud.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this library

https://github.com/mlamina/DropboxSDK-for-Android

Which allows you to utilize the DropBox API to store and retrieve data such as text content stored in a flat file. If you're looking for a database solution you'd look elsewhere. Hope that helps!